# Displaying image from server

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am trying to display an image coming from my server but it is not showing.
I tried it using Postman and it is working.

Here is my server action for sending image

```
ItemImage: async function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../assets/images/'))
    return res.status(200)
  },
```

I am trying to display the Aorus image but it is not showing.

```
<img src="/images/Aorus.png" alt="avatar">
```

Comment: Try `window.location.origin + '/images/aorus.png'`

Comment: @KieranQuinn still not showing. I dont know why but in postman my api is working just fine

Comment: According to the question: 1. You are sending a folder instead of an image. 
2. If your image is into `/assets/images/`, from client you don't have to repeat `/images`. Just put the image name like this: `<img src="/Aorus.png" alt="avatar">`.
By the way this is not the best way to serve files with Node.js. Are you using Express.js ?

Comment: @AmadouBeye I tried removing images but it is still not showing. I am using sails. I was spending my whole day searching to display an image coming from server but I still couldn't figure it out :(